# Why does `np.sum([-np.Inf, +np.Inf])` warn about "invalid value encountered in reduce"

Tags: python, numpy, nan, infinity

```bash
python -c "import numpy as np; print(np.sum([-np.Inf, +np.Inf]))"
```

gives

```
numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:86: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in reduce
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
nan
```

I wonder why that is:

1. There is no warning in

   ```bash
   python -c "import numpy as np; print(np.sum([-np.Inf, -np.Inf]))"
   ```

   nor in

   ```bash
   python -c "import numpy as np; print(np.sum([+np.Inf, +np.Inf]))"
   ```

   so it can't be the `Inf`s.
2. There is no warning in

   ```bash
   python -c "import numpy as np; print(np.sum([np.nan, np.nan]))"
   ```

   so it can't be the `NaN` result.

What is it, then, and how can I avoid it? I actually like getting `NaN` as a result, I just want to avoid the warning.

Comment: *invalid value encountered* is raised (AFAIK by the underlying OS) if the binary representation of a c-type float value doesn't match a numeric value or the specific representation of `nan` (or other special tokens). I don't know why `np.add(-np.inf, np.inf)` raises the warning, but `-np.inf + np.inf` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is fine, because `Inf - Inf` is mathematically undefined. What result would you expect?

If you want to avoid the warning, use a filter as follows:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
    res = np.sum([-np.Inf, np.Inf])
```

Comment: I would expect that `Inf - Inf == NaN`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN. That may be mathematically undefined, but it is well defined in floating point computations. And if `NaN` should generate a warning, why doesn't `np.sum([np.nan, np.nan])`?

Comment: I am not a numpy developer, but generally a warning only alerts the user of some specially handled condition and helps developers to avoid potential bugs. So if you sum a NaN, the result is always a NaN, nothing special here. However, if you sum an Inf value with other numbers the result is typically still inf, only if there is an inf with opposite sign you have the special situation which produces a NaN. I guess this is why that special case deserves special highlighting with a warning.

Comment: It *is* an explanation, but I don't find it terribly convincing ;) People who know that 5 + NaN is NaN should also know that Inf - Inf is NaN - I don't see a reason to warn about one but not the other. I reported this as a bug: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22661

Comment: My understanding is that the warning occurs when a *new* `nan` is generated, i.e. a `nan` is generated from inputs that are not `nan`. `5 + nan` does not generate a new `nan`, but `inf - inf` does.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser if you don't know it yet (I did not!), you may be interested in the concept of quiet and signaling NaNs, which may at least explain why no warnings are emitted when adding `NaN`s. See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22661#issuecomment-1326168983. I still cannot explain why np.subtract(np.inf, np.inf)` emits a warning, but I am getting closer :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer by @CarlosHorn is pretty close, although hidden deep inside the IEEE standard 754 (I checked the 2008 version).

Section 7.2 (Default exception handling > Invalid operation) writes

> The invalid operation exception is signaled if and only if *there is no usefully definable result*.

I wouldn't know what a "usefully definable result" might be, considering that some people may not find `Inf` useful; I, by contrast, find even `NaN` pretty useful. Anyay, the section gives a comprehensive list of examples, which includes (in d) the "magnitude subtraction of infinities", explaining why and form of `Inf - Inf` should be considered invalid. It does also include (in a) "any [...] operation on a signaling NaN", but does not include operations on a quiet NaN. This important distinction explains why `NaN + NaN` usually does not signal, as `np.nan` is quiet.

For completeness, section 6.1 explains why `Inf + Inf` should not be considered invalid.

Two things left to says:

- It is unclear (yet irrelevant) to me why `np.inf - np.inf` does not raise an exception.
- `with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"): ...` is probably the cleanest way to suppress the warning.

More resources:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22661#issuecomment-1326168983
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Exception_handling

Comment: Thanks @bers, great findings, I also learned about signalling NaNs here. Just to add another case which I have not seen mentioned but belongs to the same family `np.multiply(np.Inf, 0)`.

Comment: @CarlosHorn yes, that is section 7.2b) of the same standard :)